# Array self-increments

Tags: c++, arrays

A problem in a legacy system has been reduced to code which does "auto" array indexing onto itself that look like the following:

```
int x[4] = {1,2,3,4};
std::cout << x[++*+x] << " " << x[*+x+1] << "\n";
```

The code never underwent a code review for readability and maintainability, and I am trying to understand why it outputs **3** and **4**? It's unclear to me how it indexes into the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code does index into the array, but it also changes the array as it does. It is equivalent to,

```
std::cout << x[++x[0]] << " "; // the array becomes {2,2,3,4}    
std::cout << x[x[0]+1] << "\n";
```

Note that `+x` is simply the pointer address of the array. The relevant part of the standard says in `5.3.1 [expr.unary.op]`:

> The operand of the unary + operator shall have arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, or pointer type and the
>   result is the value of the argument.

Comment: The unary `+` is useless obfuscation, the code works the same without it.

Answer (score 0):

Building on mockinterface's answer. (My comment is too big to fit in a comment!)

The code is more clearly expressed as:

```
std::cout << x[++x[0]] << " " << x[x[0]+1] << "\n";
```

However, in C++98 and C++03 **this causes undefined behaviour**.
The read of `x[0]` to the right, and the increment of `x[0]` may
occur without an intervening sequence point. (Even though these
operator invocations are function calls, all of the arguments may
be evaluated before any function is called).

(C++11 changed the rules for sequencing, IDK whether this code is
now well-defined, or if so, which of those operations occurs first).

Furthermore, just the expression `x[++x[0]]` causes undefined behaviour
if `x[0] == -1` beforehand, as there is no sequence point between the
increment and the outer access of `x[0]`.

I'd recommend replacing this expression with something that does not
mix increments and reads.  For example:

```
int index = ++x[0];
if ( index >= 0 && index < (int)lengthof(x) - 1 )
     std::cout << x[index] << " " << x[index+1] << "\n";
else
     std::cout << "index out of bounds on x[]\n";
```

Comment: The code in the question with the `cout` without sequence points is just an example, the real codes looks different but "obfuscates" like I've shown all the same.